# How can delegate return the stringbuilder?

Tags: c#, c++, delegates, marshalling, stringbuilder

first

```
delegate System.Text.StringBuilder get_content_func(uint i);
```

then

```
get_content_func func = _content;
System.IntPtr p = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(func);//error - stack over flow
```

and the 'p' will be register to c++ ,and will be callback at some time to get the string content .
c++ part

```
typedef char* (__stdcall* GetContenFunc)(unsigned int id);//char*
void register_get_page_content(GetContenFunc GetHandle) {
        g_GetHandle = GetHandle;//g_GetHanle is a global pointer
}

//func to call g_GetHandle

void get_page(guid id) {
        char* content;
        if (g_GetHandle != nullptr) {
            content = g_GetHandle(id);
        }
    }
```

the purpose is to get the string from method '_content 'which is used to send to cpp to do something else. 'p' will be a callback function to get the content by stringbuilder .
but it failed,how can it solved?

Comment: why did you tag this with c++?

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis because i want to know whether it has a better way that let the cpp call the functionpointer to get the string in c#

Comment: `System.Text.StringBuilder` -- C++ has no idea what this is.  The only thing C++ knows is some sort of contiguous buffer that will contain or can contain characters, represented by a the requisite character buffer's pointer/address.

Comment: Please provide your C++ part to complete this question.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie , C++ has no idea 'System.Text.StringBuilder' ,but it can be passed as a parameter ,in c++ the para is 'char*' ，but it crashed as a return value.

Comment: Where does your `C++` function(s) actually return a value?  Of course it will crash.  The second thing is that you should *not* be returning character pointers from a DLL function.  You should instead fill any passed-in buffer from the client with the information.  Returning character pointers should be avoided totally.